# Post script to post at top of file

Tags: php

I have been using this script for a while but I would like to improve it a bit.
What this script does, it writes certain text which gets posted at a page to a text file.

But the script now posts the data to the bottom of the text file so I have to scroll all the way to the bottom all the time I want to see the new logs.

What I would like is to make it post the logs at the top of the log file.
Would that be possible? Thanks!

Script: http://pastebin.com/vc5aeA52

Comment: simple use file() and array_reverse() for output

Answer (score 1):

sure:

```
file_put_contents($yourFile, $post . "\n" . file_get_contents($yourfile));
```

Comment: Indeed the easiest solution.

Comment: not at all ... there a at least two file actions each time